# How to maintain size of ggplot with long labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that is a simple barplot of number of each type of an event. I need the labels of the plot to be under the plot as some of the events have very long names and were squashing the plot sideways. I tried to move the labels underneath the plot but it now gets squashed upwards when there are lots of event types. Is there a way of having a static plot size (i.e. for the bar graph) so that long legends don't squash the plot?

My code:

```
ggplot(counts_df, aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill - Var1)+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    theme(legen.direction = "vertical") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90)
```

The result:

[image]

I think this is because the image size must be static so the plot gets sacrificed for the axis. The same thing happens when I put a legend beneath the plot.

Comment: Would be nice to have a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: At least the plot so we can understand ?

Comment: @timat. I have added the plot

Comment: @SebastianZeki,  When you export the plot, play with `width` and `heigth` parameter so the upper part is not squas. you can also change x-label angle to 60. align the x-label on left (next to the tick), change long label so they appear on 2 lines. this will reduce the size of the x-label part.

Comment: egg::set_panel_size might help

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There a several ways to avoid overplotting of labels or squeezing the plot area or to improve readability in general. Which of the proposed solutions is most suitable will depend on the lengths of the labels and the number of bars, and a number of other factors. So, you will probably have to play around.

### Dummy data

Unfortunately, the OP hasn't included a reproducible example, so we we have to make up our own data:

```
V1 <- c("Long label", "Longer label", "An even longer label",
        "A very, very long label", "An extremely long label",
        "Long, longer, longest label of all possible labels", 
        "Another label", "Short", "Not so short label")
df <- data.frame(V1, V2 = nchar(V1))
yaxis_label <- "A rather long axis label of character counts"
```

### "Standard" bar chart

Labels on the x-axis are printed upright, overplotting each other:

```
library(ggplot2)  # version 2.2.0+
p <- ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_col() + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(yaxis_label) 
p
```

Note that the recently added  `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat="identity")` is being used.

[image]

### OP's approach: rotate labels

Labels on x-axis are rotated by 90° degrees, squeezing the plot area:

```
p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

### Horizontal bar chart

All labels (including the y-axis label) are printed upright, improving readability but still squeezing the plot area (but to a lesser extent as the chart is in landscape format):

```
p + coord_flip()
```

[image]

### Vertical bar chart with labels wrapped

Labels are printed upright, avoiding overplotting, squeezing of plot area  is reduced. You may have to play around with the `width` parameter to `stringr::str_wrap`.

```
q <- p + aes(stringr::str_wrap(V1, 15), V2) + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(yaxis_label)
q
```

[image]

### Horizontal bar chart with labels wrapped

My favorite approach: All labels are printed upright, improving readability, 
squeezing of plot area are is reduced. Again, you may have to play around with the `width` parameter to `stringr::str_wrap` to control the number of lines the labels are split into.

```
q + coord_flip()
```

[image]

### Addendum: Abbreviate labels using `scale_x_discrete()`

For the sake of completeness, it should be mentioned that `ggplot2` is able to abbreviate labels. In this case, I find the result disappointing.

```
p + scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Comment: Apologies for downvoting but this does not answer the question, which asked about how to achieve 'a static plot size (i.e. for the bar graph)'. The various options proposed here simply mitigate the extent to which the plot size will be compromised by the length of the labels. Plot size will continue to vary. If there is no way to stabilise the plot size (as opposed to the overall dimensions of the image) within ggplot2, please say so at the beginning of your answer and I will upvote (assuming that it is true).

Comment: @Uwe Your answer has been extremely useful in my case, wanted to thank you!

Answer (score 9):

To clarify, what this question appears to be asking about is *how to specify the panel size* in ggplot2.

I believe that the correct answer to this question is 'you just can't do that'.

As of the present time, there does not seem to be any parameter that can be set in any ggplot2 function that would achieve this. If there was one, I think it would most likely be in the form of `height` and `width` arguments to an `element_rect` call within a call to `theme` (which is how we make other changes to the panel, e.g. altering its background colour), but there's nothing resembling those in the docs for `element_rect` so my best guess is that specifying the panel size is impossible:

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/element.html

The following reference is old but I can't find anything more up to date that positively confirms whether or not this is the case:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/nbhph_arQ7E

In that discussion, someone asks whether it is possible to specify the panel size, and Hadley says 'Not yet, but it's on my to do list'. That was nine years ago; I guess it's still on his to do list!

Comment: I found a solution here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-i-control-the-size-of-the-panel-in-a-ggplot-so-they-are-consistent/14377/8. `cowplot::align_plots` is able to take a list of plots that have varying plot/axes areas and align them all to be the same. Haven't had time yet to dig into how it works, but looking at the function quickly it shouldn't be too hard to figure out what parameter controls the plot/axes areas.

Answer (score 6):

One more solution in addition to those above - use **staggered labels**. These can be used with text wrapping to get a fairly readable result:

```
p + scale_x_discrete(guide = ggplot2::guide_axis(n.dodge = 2), 
                     labels = function(x) stringr::str_wrap(x, width = 20))
```

(Using the plot `p` from @Uwe's answer)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found other methods didn't quite get what I wanted. I made this function to add a couple of dots after long names

```
tidy_name <- function(name, n_char) {
  ifelse(nchar(name) > (n_char - 2), 
    {substr(name, 1, n_char) %>% paste0(., "..")},
    name)
}

vec <- c("short", "medium string", "very long string which will be shortened")

vec %>% tidy_name(20)

# [1] "short"   "medium string"   "very long string whi.."
```