# ggplot axis tick labels getting cut off

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

I'm producing a `geom_tile` `ggplot` and my x-axis tick labels are long:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(sample = c(rep(paste(rep("S1",30),collapse=""),30),
                            rep(paste(rep("S2",30),collapse=""),30),
                            rep(paste(rep("S3",30),collapse=""),30)),
                 gene = rep(paste("G", 1:30, sep = ""), 90),
                 value = rnorm(90))
```

So when I produce the plot they get cut off:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = sample, y = gene)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
    scale_fill_gradient2(high = "darkred", low = "darkblue") +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.key = element_blank(), 
          legend.position = "right", 
          axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
          panel.border = element_blank(), 
          strip.background = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: put some line breaks in there?

Comment: I prefer to expand the area of the plot so it wraps the labels

Comment: will the the `str_wrap` answer here work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878974/auto-wrapping-of-labels-via-labeller-label-wrap-in-ggplot2

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to wrap the labels, then you could increase the left margin of the plot, though that will also result in a lot of empty white space above the diagonal label. If you want to go with that option add `theme(plot.margin=margin(5,5,5,50,unit="pt"))`, (or whatever margin values work for you) where the order of the margin values is top, right, bottom, left. The default units are "pt", but you can use "lines", "in", or "cm" as well.

Comment: As far as I understand str_wrap will work character vectors of length > 1, whereas my labels have length = 1.  In addition, personally I think that expanding the plot are rather than breaking down the labels is a more elegant solution

Comment: Thanks @eipi10. I don't suppose ggplot can figure out automatically how much margin I need to include the labels in the plot area?

Comment: If you want to get fancy, you could probably use the width of the string (`strwidth` is the base graphics function, but you probably need a grid graphics function for this case) its angle and the distance of the tick mark from the edge of the plot area to figure out the amount of overhang programmatically.

Comment: `str_wrap` from the `stringr` package will wrap an individual string. There also [base `strwrap` combined with `paste`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29847221/496488).

Comment: Just flip your x and y aesthetics and ditch the angle so people aren't cocking their heads to read your plot.

Comment: Please, see my answer to the Q [_How to maintain size of ggplot with large legends_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41607201/3817004) for different possibilities to deal with long labels.