# Wrap axis label when using ggplotly()

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to create a horizontal bar chart using `ggplotly()`. Because the labels are rather long I inserted HTML line breaks `<br>`. When plotting the data using `ggplotly()` the label is indeed wrapped but there is big margin to the left of the label basically rendering the wrapping useless. Is there any way to fix this besides using `plot_ly()`?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(a = "A very long label<br>that needs<br>to be wrapped", b = 10)

ggplotly({
  ggplot(df, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
})
```

[image]

```r
plot_ly(df, y = ~a, x = ~b, type = "bar", orientation = "h")
```

[image]

Comment: [This answer on How to maintain size of ggplot with long labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607201/3817004) elaborates different options for `ggplot2` which may work for `ggplotly` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to @asafpr's answer, adjusting the left margin using `plotly::layout()` does the job:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(a = "A very long label<br>that needs<br>to be wrapped", b = 10)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()

ggploty(p) %>%
  layout(margin = list(l = 10))
```

[image]

Interestingly, the value passed onto `l` does not seem to matter:

```r
ggploty(p) %>%
  layout(margin = list(l = 10))
```

[image]

```r
ggploty(p) %>%
  layout(margin = list(l = 1000))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the margins of the ggplot with `plot.margin` in `theme`:

```
ggplotly({
     ggplot(df, aes(a, b)) +
         geom_col() +
         coord_flip() + theme(plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,-4, "cm"))
 })
```

[image]