# How to wrap an X-axis label when using aes_string?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

[This lovely answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607201/34935) shows how to wrap long labels in a bar chart.  In short `stringr::str_wrap`.  Recap:

```
V1 <- c("Long label", "Longer label", "An even longer label",
        "A very, very long label", "An extremely long label",
        "Long, longer, longest label of all possible labels", 
        "Another label", "Short", "Not so short label")
df <- data.frame(V1, V2 = nchar(V1))
yaxis_label <- "A rather long axis label of character counts"
library(ggplot2)  # version 2.2.0+
p <- ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_col() + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(yaxis_label) 
p + aes(stringr::str_wrap(V1, 15), V2) + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(yaxis_label)
```

Suppose I'm using `geom_histogram(stat="count")` to make the bars, and I'm using `aes_string` because I'm automating multiple plots.  Now how do I wrap the labels?

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1=rep(df$V1, df$V2))
# works
q <- ggplot(df2, aes(V1)) + geom_histogram(stat="count") + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(yaxis_label)
q + aes(stringr::str_wrap(V1, 15)) + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(yaxis_label)
```

but

```
# doesn't wrap
r <- ggplot(df2, aes_string(stringr::str_wrap(varname, 15))) +
  geom_histogram(stat="count") + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(yaxis_label) 
r
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `labels` arguments of `scale_x_discrete()`. This function will be applied to the axis labels before plotting.

```r
ggplot(df2, aes_string("V1")) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) stringr::str_wrap(x, width = 10))
```

[image]